# esbuild import css as a string

Tags: css, import, inline, vite, esbuild

I am using vite to build a component library. I use css?inline like this

```js
import otherStyles from './bar.css?inline' // will be available as a string
```

And use the string to construct stylesheets in the component. [see here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#disabling-css-injection-into-the-page)

Now I made a build script with esbuild. But can't seem to get this inline css to work. Esbuild parses the import but makes an external css.

I know vite (dev env) is based on esbuild, so it should be possible to let esbuild do inline css parsing. Can't find it in the [docs](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#css-from-js), can't find a [plugin](https://github.com/esbuild/community-plugins) that does this either.

Comment: you probably need to create a custom plugin, see this [article](https://dev.to/rxliuli/using-the-esbuild-plug-in-mechanism-to-achieve-the-desired-functionality-4fh9) and scroll to "Binding text files via ?raw" which should be similar to "?inline".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/claviska/esbuild-plugin-inline-import

Usage:

```js
import string from 'inline:./path/to/file.ext';
```

f.e.

```js
import cssCode from 'inline:./path/to/style.css';
```